# Subversion: Copy repository users from existing to new project (SASL Database)

Tags: database, svn, sasl

Is it possible to copy the sasl (which contains username + pw) database from one repository to another?

The reason Im asking that is the following:
Everytime you create a new project in SVN it opens up a repository for it. So be it.

Unfortunately it does not copy the existing users of another (selectable) already existing project into the new one. (Im talking of the sasl database).

Answer (score 1):

You are using svnserve?

I'd suggest using Apache for serving the repository. That way you get all the flexibility that Apache provides for restricting repository access.